# Editing Launcher2.apk (in android 4.1) with eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse

I've **googled**, asked, searched, done everything but I don't have enough info about my questions.
Here it is:
I'm working on a project. For this project, I must **add a tab panel** (called education) top of launcher next to applications and widgets tabs. [Here](http://fs02.androidpit.info/ass/x97/6294097-1342709440417.jpg) you can see.
But I'm a beginner and there is **nothing** on the web. Any documents, vides etc.. Yes, you can say "there are too many but you couldn't see". But all of this documents about 4.0 ICS or 2.2

I need an information about android 4.1 JB.Here is my question exactly:
I've downloaded all of sdk files and I'm sure that I included adt to eclipse (because some options are enabled) but even I can't see create a new android project option.

The second problem: I included the launcher2 file (I got it from original source file) but eclipse showed me too many error. They can't be real errors because 'Launcher2.apk' is a working file on Android 4.1 JB you know :)

Yes, please help me to editing **Android 4.1 JB**'s launcher for adding a new tab panel.. Thank you.. (Sorry for my english and inexperience)

(Pictures are here. Take a look)

[image: Errors]
[image: New Android Project]

Comment: New Android Project is now called "Android Application Project"

Comment: If you have the source to Launcher2 then just go to File->Import->Android->Existing Android Project into workspace. Then you should probably need to run Clean and Build, if you don't already have Automatically build set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Android Project is now called "Android Application Project"

If you have the source to Launcher2 then just go to `File->Import->Android->Existing Android Project into workspace`. Then you should probably need to run Clean and Build, if you don't already have "Build Automatically" set.

---

**Edit:**

Okay, after looking at your images and doing some more research I need you check something out for me.

1. Open up `FocusHelper.java`
2. Look at all of the import statements at the top.
3. If you see any that reads `import android.R` then delete that line.
4. Save the file and see if that removes some of these errors you are getting.
5. If that works then you'll need to go into each error throwing file and repeat steps 2 and 3.

I have run into this issue before and doing those steps cleared this up for me. [It seems to be a common Eclipse bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

*Also, your SDK build is set to Android 4.0 API 14 but from what I am reading on the `Advanceable` class you'll need API level 16, which is 4.1.*

---

**Edit 2:**

When I tried doing this I found that there are lots of missing declarations which you'll have to go through and declare yourself, there are also import references that aren't found, you'll have to either find them and import them into your project and reference them accordingly or remove them and have a slightly less functional Launcher. [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668334/1134705).

First thing first, I found that when you initially import the project, if a `R.java` doesn't auto-generate in the `gen/com.android.launcher/` package then just create an XML dummy file in your `res/values/` folder (you could quite possibly do this anywhere inside the `res` folder) and it will then generate an `R.java` at that point, then delete that file. You **WILL** need the `import com.android.launcher.R;` line but at this point you should see a LOT of errors clear out, assuming your settings are set to "Build Automatically". Once that is complete then double click on each error line and it will take you to that error, you can fix by declaring variables (and initializing them in most, if not all cases), pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+O`, removing `@Override`, etc. You will NOT have all the functionality, but once complete you will have something to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I got 'android application project'..

I hit clean button but still errors are here, And the build button is disabled. I can't hit it.

If you say okey, I can send you photos of errors..

Comment: Can you print screen the errors and upload and send me the links, I'll take a look at them and see if I can help you.

Comment: here: 
http://goo.gl/yBsCE
and here is the launcher2 source code (haven't compiled): http://goo.gl/jHnCI
please take a look, thank you..

Comment: Check out the edit I just made to my answer, I think this could fix your issues. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you man..
But I saw this line import com.android.launcher.R; like you said import android.r and I deleted it. I Saved the file but still there are the same error. Can you open the launcher that I sent with your eclipse and say me does your eclipse have errors?.. About android version, how can I change it to api 16? or what should I do about this prob.? Thank you for your help and I don't find any other man for help me :)

Comment: I ran into the same errors as you, it would take too long for me to look into rebuilding the source to make it work. Seems like a lot of people are having those same errors when importing Launcher2 source. Have you thought about getting the [ADWLauncher source](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/) instead??

Comment: Check my new answer, also remember to change your build path to API 16. Sorry I couldn't help you more, but I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to build Launcher using the Android SDK because it uses some private APIs (the errors you are seeing).

Comment: But, how could google do? There are a lot of java file. I can't see anyother file. Just a pyhton file. Can I add API's to eclipse (to my project)?

Comment: You can build it using make in the whole Android tree, not as a separate app.

Comment: I don't understand. Give me an example :S

Comment: you say, I cannot build only the launcher ? but why?