# Can't compile the Gallery2 project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I downloaded the project folder from :

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/
```

For some reason, when I opened it into my Eclipse environment, it is not compiling and it shows a lot of broken references. I am attaching screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Any ideas if I am doing something wrong or the code itself has issues?

Comment: What are some of the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

This is a platform package, not a stand alone 3rd party package.  It uses classes which are part of the platform, but not the Android SDK.  It's built with the platform as a whole using make rather than Eclipse and ultimately is in the ROM (i.e. flash image.)  You won't be able to build it with Eclipse and try to deploy it.

Comment: If I can not build it in Eclipse, is there any way to compile it otherwise? also if the code is not build-able then I would guess that Google posts it just for reference and nothing else?

Comment: If I can not compile this aplicaiton then does it mean that if someone wants to extend the code of Gallery application by adding their own code, I am assuming they might need to compile it first and then go ahead and change the code. How would they achieve that?

Comment: Since this is a platform package, it cannot easily be built with Eclipse.  It relies on packages/APIs which are part of the platform, which are different than the ones considered "public" Android APIs which are rolled into the Android SDK.  In order to extend it as a stand alone app, you'd have to remove the platform API dependencies and replace them with your own implementation or a public SDK equivalent.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Many of Android's core apps depend on internal system APIs that are not available in the standard SDK that developers compile against. You can find some more information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666521/easy-way-to-build-android-system-app-eclipse-for-exemple).