# Build and reuse android open source Dialer source code in my project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have to integrate android opensource Dialer source code into my application and also need to do customizations on the same.

1. Currently I cloned the Dialer source code from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/
2. **It doesn't seems to be a gradle project. How can I build this project ?**
3. I need to **add this entire project as reusable module in my project**. Could you please help me on this. How can I start with this ?

This Answer seems very informative https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668334/3020568 but I need to get some more help from guys those who tried to build this type of applications.

WE tried below steps.

1. Checked out source code from google source.
2. Tried to import the project in Android Studio.
3. It has dependencies outside the project which are not able to resolve. - Some classes and methods has no reference inside the source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're trying to create a custom dialer application, you can follow this tutorial http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/simple-dialer-application/ to use it in Android Studio, select import Eclipse project

Comment: @Steve I do not exactly need to create a custom dialer from scratch. I need to include dialer part from default android dialer source code + my custom features

Comment: In the **File->New->Import Module** you can the select the destination directory of the module.Hope this helps

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this is for future reference.

You cannot build the Dialer application without access to the rest of the source code. You need to first download the whole Android source (AOSP) and then build it because the Dialer application that comes with AOSP requires some framework files which is included in AOSP; hence the Dialer code may not actually work on all devices. Your best bet is using a tutorial to build a dialer application from scratch.